# How to Use Python to launch a Program with parameters behind in the shortcut?

Tags: python

I want to Launch my ERP Software using Python as I am trying to self Teach myself to do RPA in Python. I need to launch the software and login, but I am having difficulties loading it.

How to I launch the software with a path like this in the shortcut?

C:\SYSPRO7Client\Base\SYSPROClient.exe /WCF=192.168.10.10:2222 /BASEDIR=1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming windows shortcuts with the blue arrow bottom left, you can edit their properties directly with the GUI and pass parameters in directly (the quotes `"` are not needed).

If you wanted to use Python as a part of a script or something to run that program with the path in the properties field in a windows shortcut, then you can use `subprocess` like this.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['C:\\SYSPRO7Client\\Base\\SYSPROClient.exe', ' /WCF=192.168.10.10:2222', '/BASEDIR=1'])
```

note that you have to escape the back slashes `\` and separate the parameters passed to the program.

Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command).